# Cannot convert from List<Bar> to List<Foo>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have a set up like this:

```
abstract class Foo {}
class Bar : Foo {}
```

and a method elsewhere of this form:

```
void AddEntries(List<Foo>) {}
```

I am trying to call this method using a list of objects of type `Bar`

```
List<Bar> barList = new List<Bar>()
AddEntries(barList);
```

but this gives me the error:

> cannot convert from List<Bar> to List<Foo>

Is there anyway around this problem?  I Need to keep the method definition using the abstract class.

Comment: Does C# have syntax like `List<? extends Foo>` like Java does?

Comment: @dbush Yes, C#'s version is in the accepted answer

Comment: @harrichael Though unlike Java, C# supports generic covariance, so there is an even better option (see Rob's answer)

Comment: I actually suspect Rob's answer is better because I bet OP is adding the passed entries to an aggregated list, instead of mutating the argument.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could make your `AddEntries` generic and change it to this

```
void AddEntries<T>(List<T> test) where T : Foo
{
    //your logic 
}
```

Have a look at [Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for further information.

Answer (score 60):

Have a read of [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics from learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) as this, particularly the section *"Generic Interfaces with Covariant Type Parameters"* will cover off the scenario that you're working with.

In short, if you (can) change the signature of your `AddEntries` method to:

```
static void AddEntries(IEnumerable<Foo> entries)
```

(Note the use of `IEnumerable<Foo>` instead of `List<Foo>`) you'll be able to do what you're looking to do.

The specific difference here is that the `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>` are declared differently:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ... ...
```

The difference that *matters* is the `out` in the declaration of `IEnumerable<T>` which indicates that it is *covariant* which means (with the definition taken from learn.microsoft.com):

> **Covariance**: Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.

Comment: Considering that the method name is AddEntries it's unlikely that OP can use IEnumerable.

Comment: @Taemyr The OP can, however, define an `interface`.

Comment: @Taemyr: I assume `AddEntries` means "Add these entries to some other list", not "Add some entries to this list".  Otherwise neither answer will work for him, since he can't add a `FooChild` to a `List<Bar>` regardless.

Comment: I'll just add, because I can never remember which is which (and reading that definition doesn't help), that the C# syntax for co/contra variance is fantastic, because it allows you to express whether your methods will receive something of a type _in_, or if they will pass it _out_. If you take them in, you can take a subtype (so can be casted to a more derived type); if you pass them _out_ you can always just cast it to the less derived supertype (a list takes the type _in_ and _out_, which is why it is must be invariant). Great choice of keywords which expresses the intent clearly.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, that was my line of thought as well =)

Answer (score 43):

This is not allowed for a simple reason. Assume the below compiles:

```
AddEntries(new List<Bar>());

void AddEntries(List<Foo> list)
{
   // list is a `List<Bar>` at run-time
   list.Add(new SomethingElseDerivingFromFoo()); // what ?!
}
```

If your code would compile, you have an unsafe addition (which makes the whole generic lists pointless) where you added `SomethingElseDerivingFromFoo` to actually a `List<Bar>` (runtime type).

To solve your problem, you can use generics:

```
void AddEntries<T>(List<T> list) where T:Foo
{

}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for explaining *why* you can't do the cast, rather than just showing a way to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand. This is a [perfectly valid piece of code](http://ideone.com/xoNJX8). You just cannot rely on any additional functionality provided in the derived class (without explicit casting).

Comment: @Phylogenesis You can't pass `List<Bar>` to `AddEntries` because if you added `SomethingElseDerivingFromFoo` to that list, it would be an odd behavior (You have a `SomethingElseDerivingFromFoo` item in a `List<Bar>`. The above code I posted perfectly compile.

Comment: Oh, okay. After your edit, your explanation makes more sense.